# $|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)| \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B).$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and at least one of $\mu^*(A)$ and $\mu^*(B)$ is finite.
Show that $|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)| \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B).$

Comment: Is $\mu^*$ an outer measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works.

If $\mu^*(A)=+\infty$ and $\mu^*(B)<+\infty$, then $|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)|=+\infty$ and $\mu^*(A\triangle B) \geq \mu^*(A\backslash B)$. So, since $\mu^*(A\backslash B)=+\infty$ (you can argue by contraddiction), $|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)|=\mu^*(A\triangle B)$ follows.

If $\mu^*(A),\mu^*(B)<+\infty$, you have
$$\mu^*(A\triangle B) \geq \mu^*(A \cup B) - \mu^*(A \cap B)$$
and since
$$ \mu^*(A \cap B) \leq \mu^*(A),\mu^*(B)\leq \mu^*(A \cup B)$$
the required inequality follows.

Answer (score 2):

First, let $\mu^*(A)$ and $\mu^*(B)$ both be finite. Then, since $A \subseteq A \cup B = (A\Delta B) \cup B$, the following holds:
$$
\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(A \cup B) = \mu^*((A\Delta B) \cup B) \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B) + \mu^*(B) \iff \mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B) \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B)
$$
Doing the same estimation for $\mu^*(B)$ (use that $A \cup B = (A\Delta B) \cup A$) yields
$$
\mu^*(B) - \mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B),
$$
so we have
$$
\lvert \mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B) \rvert \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B)
$$
in total.

If without loss of generality $\mu^*(A) = \infty$ but $\mu^*(B) < \infty$, then
$$
\infty = \mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B) \leq \mu^*(A \Delta B)
$$
still holds, which means $\mu^*(A \Delta B)= \infty$.